# Why is my ListView losing data on postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm sure there's a really simple explanation for this but I've been tearing my hair out too long now so I appeal to SO for the sake of my sanity!

It's this simple: I have a `ListView` which is bound when the page first loads (and **not** again on postback). It's part of a form. On the first load I see the list of items but when I postback I see the `EmptyDataTemplate`. Is this correct behaviour? I'm sure that `ListView` as a data binding control should persist its list over postbacks. Here's the code, first front end:

```
<asp:ListView ID="boxes" runat="server" ItemType="Model.Generic.ILookupEntity<int>" EnableViewState="true">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div>
            <ul class="contact-list checkbox-row">
                <li id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
            </ul>
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="cb" runat="server" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="value" runat="server" Value="<%# Item.Key %>" />
                    <span><%# Item.Value %></span>
                </label>
            </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <p>No data</p>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:ListView>

<asp:CheckBoxList ID="boxtemp" runat="server" />
```

Then back end:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            var items = new List<Model.Generic.LookupEntity<int>>()
            {
                new Model.Generic.LookupEntity<int>(1, "One"),
                new Model.Generic.LookupEntity<int>(2, "Two"),
                new Model.Generic.LookupEntity<int>(3, "Three"),
                new Model.Generic.LookupEntity<int>(4, "Four"),
            };

            boxes.DataSource = items;
            boxes.DataBind();

            boxtemp.DataSource = items;
            boxtemp.DataTextField = "Value";
            boxtemp.DataValueField = "Key";
            boxtemp.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

I've added the boxtemp `CheckBoxList` as a test. This one retains its data on postback. But the `ListView` doesn't. What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE 1**

What's even weirder is that if I add the following code and debug, the variable `test` references the value **4** even on postback. But when the posted page is rendered I still see the `EmptyItemTemplate`.

```
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);

        var test = boxes.Items.Count;
    }
```

**UPDATE 2**

Having had it confirmed that this is not expected behaviour I have now found the cause I think. The `ListView` is inside a user control which is calling `this.DataBind()` on `PreRender`. I presume this is causing all data bound controls inside to re-bind on postback. The weird thing is that if I handle the `ListView`'s `OnDataBinding` and `OnDataBound` events, on post back I can observe that the list still contains 4 items during both events. But is still rendered displaying the `EmptyDataTemplate`. Given this scenario, and assuming that the parent control's `DataBind` call is required, can anyone suggest the best resolution?

Comment: are you familiar with PostBacks? what you could is read up on PostBack behavior.. also where is your else if it  is a postback..?

Comment: Yes, very familiar, which is why I don't understand this behaviour. The ListView should persist its data on the post back right? No 'else' because I don't want to do anything if posting back (other than handle submission on click event).

Comment: can you make the protected static or store the object is a Session Variable and cast it back as a `(ListView)Session["YourVariable"]`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how this will help. I'm asking why the ListView doesn't persist its bound items across post backs.

Comment: You are using OnInit, this method is invoked earlier  when ViewState have not been initialized. Any problem with using OnLoad?

Comment: Why are you binding oninit and not on page load ? I think initiation is not for binding can you change to page load and see

Comment: No, that's where I started. Moved to OnInit on advice elsewhere. Same impact on Page_Load. Are you confirming that this is not expected behaviour? As I mentioned, the CheckBoxList _is_ persisting its data.

Comment: Well I should see more of your code to figure out what is going on. Generally you don't place code in OnInit that manipulate control content because it is not guarantee that they have been created and that event handlers are properly wired at this point in the lifecycle. For that stuffs you should use OnLoad

Comment: I've changed it to OnLoad in my example. As I said, it makes no difference to the behaviour I'm describing.

Comment: I'm not. Those are two different controls. One is a ListView which demonstrates my issue. The other is a CheckBoxList - this one retains its data on postback.

Comment: I'm trying to recreate your issue, but there is no definition of Model here.  Can you supply that's definition, Model.Generic.LookupEntity is?

Comment: For those following, I added an update at the end of my question.

Comment: Model.Generic is a namespace. LookupEntity<T> is a simple class with Key property of type T (in this case integer) and string Value property. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out.. but honestly, if you want better help, you should provide a *COMPILABLE* example.  I have to figure out various problems, like this it takes a lot more time.  I also had to define the ILookupEntity interface, which you also didn't define.  Regardless, I created a new project with just your example, and it works just fine, persisting the values across submits.  Whatever your problem is, it's in something you are not showing here.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I think I may have tracked down the source of this now. Adding update to original question.